# Trigger script on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
jQuery({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: 38}, {
duration: 1500, easing:'swing',
step: function() {
    $('#grow1').text(Math.ceil(this.someValue));
}
});
```

How can i make sure the animation doesn't start until the user scrolls down to a particular div?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like http://scrollmagic.io. It allows you to define some triggers in the page and then execute callbacks (in this case your animation) when those triggers are reached by the user. Take a look at this example: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/custom_actions.html

Hope this will help you